# Spyder python ide uses 600MB of Ram with no programs open

Tags: spyder

I use Spyder for Python program development. When I open spyder with no programs in the editor tabs it still consumes over 600 MB of my Win 10 ram. Anyone know why or care. I know Visual studio uses an order of magnitude less memory

Comment: This question is for the Spyder developers.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I can't easily test on Windows, but on Linux all processes associated to VSCode (which are like 10) consume ~300 Mb of RAM at beginning and I've seen them increase up to ~4Gb some time ago (it depends on your extensions, of course). Spyder and its processes start at ~60 Mb and increase to ~400 Mb with time. Give the amount of RAM available these days, I don't think that's too much.

Comment: I use Spyder 5 with Anaconda 3.  If I start with no tabs in the IDE I'm at 550 MB. It's not a problem per se I'm just curious. You're right about VS, I checked and it was using about 350 MB with no tabs in the IDE.